# HTML5 input type number removes decimal places on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make the HTML5 number field display trailing zeroes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790561/how-can-i-make-the-html5-number-field-display-trailing-zeroes)

I'm trying to input a money value like "1.00", but when I enter this value the 0s are removed and it becomes "1", but if I input 1.11, it remains 1.11.

I'm using `<input type="number">`. I've tried using patterns but the extra 0s are always deleted. Also this only happens on iPhone with type="number"

Does anyone know how to get around this? Perhaps a way to use type="text", but have the phone open the numeric view?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I used for my mobile shopping [calculator](http://calc.btask.net).

```
<input type="number" name="price" step="0.01" min="0.01" max="99" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work on mobile Safari.

Comment: Works fine on my iPhone.

Comment: I'm on iOS6 and I tested on your calculator and it still removes the extra 0s

Comment: This doesn't work on Safari or iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible trick:

Using `position:absolute` and `visilibity:hidden`, position your `number` input on top of a `text` input. Then, using an `onchange` event handler on the number input, put `parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2)` into the text input.