# Regex to remove all but the last occurrence of a single character

Tags: regex

Our sanitisation on a salary input replaces all characters other than numerics (0-9) and points (.) with a blank string.

`[^0-9.]`

Which results in a string like "£63,000.00" becoming "63000.00", which can easily be converted to a float. Now I want to sanitise the case where users have used a point as the thousand separator as well as the decimal separator (eg "63.000.00"). How would I write the regex to remove all but the *LAST* point character in a string?

Comment: regex is the wrong tool for internationalizing numbers.

Comment: Are you always guaranteed to have two digits after the decimal?

Comment: No, users input all sorts of funny stuff. But if they put 2 decimals I'm relatively confident that stripping them all but keeping the last one will achieve the desired affect. I can assure you the calculation they get back on the front end will make it quite clear how the number is being interpretted.

Comment: @zzzzBov is there really a country that legitimately uses the decimal point for BOTH the thousand separator and the decimal separator? I am treating this as a typo handling feature, not internationalisation feature.

Comment: If the input is coming from HTML, you can always [enforce data format there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14650932/477563).  Probably less painful then guessing at their format after the fact.

Comment: @MartinJoiner, [welcome to i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Examples_of_use).

Comment: @Mr.Llama Although we leverage many HTML5 features we don't use type="number" because it doesn't support comma-separated thousands. We have found that many users do enter a salary as "50,000" rather than "50000" so restricting their freedom to use commas would needlessly damage user experience. I personally find 4 consecutive zeros very hard to read without the comma.

Comment: @zzzzBov We've dropped support for IE6, we're not going to start supporting an out-dated form of Spanish handwriting.

Comment: @MartinJoiner, you've apparently missed the point of my original statement. If you're looking to internationalize how you handle currency, use a library that has already solved the edge cases for you. A clumsy regex is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this rgex for replacement:

```
\.(?![^.]+$)|[^0-9.]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ3jG1/1)

replace by empty string.