# html5 input for money/currency

Tags: html, currency-formatting

I seem unable to work out what to use for accepting monetary values on a form.

I have tried...

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10000" step="1" name="Broker_Fees" id="broker_fees" required="required">
```

But that then won't allow for pence entries.

I want the incremental button control to go up in pounds, but still want the ability to enter pence.

Who would want to use an incremental button that moved 1p at a time?

Perhaps I'm using the wrong control , but I can't find a money/currency control?

Can someone please advise the best way to accept monetary values (including commas, decimal places and currency symbol) using HTML5?

Comment: You have to specify the `step` attribute with decimal places. See: [Is there a float input type in HTML(5)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5)

Comment: Please read the question again, and be sure you understand I had already done this and it produces undesired results... how can this be a duplication of the other thread under these circumstances.

Comment: Well, you are asking for "the best way to accept monetary values". Accepting an input is not the same as providing alternative input methods. Using a number input, the user can still directly insert a valid number that matches the given attributes. You can still add additional buttons, that increment by pounds…

Comment: Unfortunatley you can't control this with HTML5. But maybe this might be interesting for you: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/UC6tG/embedded/result,html,js,css/

Comment: Thanks farkas, but I can't seem to make it work, the spin buttons don't do anything and I can't type in the input either. Seems to work in FF but not IE

Comment: Keep in mind that at least Chrome forbids entering commas, if your format uses them instead of dots, like `25,50` instead of `25.50`

Answer (score 107):

**Enabling Fractions/Cents/Decimals for Number Input**

To allow fractions on an number input, you need to specify the `step` attribute to `any`:

```html
<input type="number" min="1" step="any" />
```

This will specifically keep Chrome from displaying an error when a decimal/fractional currency is entered into the input. Mozilla, IE, etc... don't error out if you forget to specify `step="any"`. W3C spec states that step="any" should, indeed, be needed to allow for decimals. So, you should definitely use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step

*Note that if you want the up/down buttons to do a specific granularity, then you must specify a numeric step such as ".01".*

Also, the number input is now pretty widely supported (>90% of users).

---

**What Input Options are there for Money/Currency?**

The title of the question has since changed and takes on a slightly different meaning. One could use both number or text input in order to accept money/decimals.

***For an input field for currency/money, it is recommended to use input type of number and specify appropriate attributes as outlined above. As of 2020, there is not a W3C spec for an actual input type of currency or money.***

Main reason being it automatically coerces the users into entering a valid standard currency format and disallows any alphanumeric text. With that said, you could certainly use the regular text input and do some post processing to only grab the numeric/decimal value (there should be server side validation on this at some point as well).

The OP detailed a requirement of currency symbols and commas. If you want fancier logic/formatting like that, (as of 2020) you'll need to create custom JS logic for a text input or find a plugin.

Answer (score 85):

Try using `step="0.01"`, then it will step by a penny each time.

eg:

```html
<input type="number" min="0.00" max="10000.00" step="0.01" />
```

Comment: This works well. But worth noting it cycles through numbers like "1.28... 1.29... **1.3...** 1.31...". I.e. trailing zeros are absent (because it's a number not currency). Related: [How can I make the HTML5 number field display trailing zeroes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790561/how-can-i-make-the-html5-number-field-display-trailing-zeroes)

Comment: and remember not all languages use decimal for their monetary system.

Comment: Amazing that html doesn't have a price type....where's the common sense in the world of e-commerce

Answer (score 50):

### Using javascript's [Number.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```js
var currencyInput = document.querySelector('input[type="currency"]')
var currency = 'GBP' // https://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/lists/list_one.xml

 // format inital value
onBlur({target:currencyInput})

// bind event listeners
currencyInput.addEventListener('focus', onFocus)
currencyInput.addEventListener('blur', onBlur)


function localStringToNumber( s ){
  return Number(String(s).replace(/[^0-9.,-]+/g,""))
}

function onFocus(e){
  var value = e.target.value;
  e.target.value = value ? localStringToNumber(value) : ''
}

function onBlur(e){
  var value = e.target.value

  var options = {
      maximumFractionDigits : 2,
      currency              : currency,
      style                 : "currency",
      currencyDisplay       : "symbol"
  }
  
  e.target.value = (value || value === 0) 
    ? localStringToNumber(value).toLocaleString(undefined, options)
    : ''
}
```

```css
input{
  padding: 10px;
  font: 20px Arial;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<input type='currency' value="123" placeholder='Type a number & click outside' />
```

[Here's a very simple demo](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/MWjdbgL?editors=1100) illustrating the above method (HTML-only)

---

I've made a tiny [*React* component](https://github.com/yairEO/react-number-input) if anyone's interested

Comment: This is a tidy solution, but beware the localStringToNumber conversion will fail for users in some countries. For example, France uses a comma for a decimal point. In this case, the starting value of 123 gets converted to 123,00 (correctly) but then changes to 12300 on focus and 12300,00 on blur. Essentially, every focus and blur inadvertently multiplies the value by 100!

Comment: @peteredhead - how to reproduce? Did you change the `currency` variable to something else?

Comment: The first argument of toLocaleString is the locale to use for formatting. In your code it's set to undefined and therefore uses the browser / system settings. If you want to test how it would work for a user in another country, you could set it to "fr-FR" for example

Comment: Very interesting. Here's a [list of countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) which uses *comma* vs. *decimal point*

Comment: [I see it is very difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25645163/104380) to convert numbers (in different locales which are represented as *Strings*) back to numbers. There are many different numeral systems. It would require detecting the correct locale and apply a transformation function accordingly. many transformation functions are to be prepared in advance which will bloat the codebase. so sad.

Comment: @vsync This works great apart from it will only affect the first input set as currency type. If you have multiple inputs set as currency, only the first one will work. I am not knowledgeable enough to understand why. Do you have any insight as to why this could be the case?

Comment: The code is meant for an ad-hoc demonstration on Stackoverflow, not intended as a complete program which is able do copy-pasted to already-existing code without modifications/re-write. I can guess why it did not work for you. It seems it would be best for your to hire an expect which can integrate my solution for you

Comment: @vsync I managed to figure it out. I posted a reply on this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65545183/1238706I have credited you with the bulk of the code. It may have been an example but it has worked well for me . Thanks

Comment: This does not work. It multiplies and divides by 100 on every blur and focus cycle

Comment: @Ferrybig - [it *does* work](https://tenor.com/view/gif-27693831)

Comment: @vsync Your link is a 404. This is what I'm seeing: https://i.imgur.com/ZmxgUHt.gif It does some weird multiplication and division by 100 every click

Comment: @Ferrybig - which browser/OS?

Comment: This is Firefox on Arch Linux, set to the NL-nl locale (the locale here has , as the decimal separator)

Comment: @Ferrybig - I've now added the `,` character to the Regex which transforms the String to a Number format

Comment: The behavior seems worse now, after the page is loaded the value is being shown on screen as "<pound symbol> 123,00". Clicking on the field changes it "NaN". When you try to type in it, it only accepts input with the dot as the decimal separator, other decimal formatters get changed to NaN after an unblur. if an user would interact with this, they see the value inside the box has a comma as separator, so they assume the page works with a comma. Comparing this with an `input type=number`, which does not accept a thousand separator, and accepts both the , and . as the decimal separator

Comment: This example has `GBP` as hard-coded currency, so it expects the input to match obviously. You are **not** expected to use `,` (commas) for Pounds-currency value. You can change the code to automatically match your system's currency.

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled across this article looking for a similar answer. I read @vsync example [Using javascript's Number.prototype.toLocaleString:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54534797/1238706) and it appeared to work well. The only complaint I had was that if you had more than a single `input type="currency"` within your page it would only modify the first instance of it.

As he mentions in his comments it was only designed as an example for stackoverflow.

However, the example worked well for me and although I have little experience with JS I figured out how to modify it so that it will work with multiple `input type="currency"` on the page using the `document.querySelectorAll` rather than `document.querySelector` and adding a for loop.

I hope this can be useful for someone else. ( Credit for the bulk of the code is @vsync )

```
var currencyInput = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="currency"]' );

for ( var i = 0; i < currencyInput.length; i++ ) {

    var currency = 'GBP'
    onBlur( {
        target: currencyInput[ i ]
    } )

    currencyInput[ i ].addEventListener( 'focus', onFocus )
    currencyInput[ i ].addEventListener( 'blur', onBlur )

    function localStringToNumber( s ) {
        return Number( String( s ).replace( /[^0-9.-]+/g, "" ) )
    }

    function onFocus( e ) {
        var value = e.target.value;
        e.target.value = value ? localStringToNumber( value ) : ''
    }

    function onBlur( e ) {
        var value = e.target.value

        var options = {
            maximumFractionDigits: 2,
            currency: currency,
            style: "currency",
            currencyDisplay: "symbol"
        }

        e.target.value = ( value || value === 0 ) ?
            localStringToNumber( value ).toLocaleString( undefined, options ) :
            ''
    }
}
```

```js
    var currencyInput = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="currency"]' );

    for ( var i = 0; i < currencyInput.length; i++ ) {

        var currency = 'GBP'
        onBlur( {
            target: currencyInput[ i ]
        } )

        currencyInput[ i ].addEventListener( 'focus', onFocus )
        currencyInput[ i ].addEventListener( 'blur', onBlur )

        function localStringToNumber( s ) {
            return Number( String( s ).replace( /[^0-9.-]+/g, "" ) )
        }

        function onFocus( e ) {
            var value = e.target.value;
            e.target.value = value ? localStringToNumber( value ) : ''
        }

        function onBlur( e ) {
            var value = e.target.value

            var options = {
                maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                currency: currency,
                style: "currency",
                currencyDisplay: "symbol"
            }

            e.target.value = ( value || value === 0 ) ?
                localStringToNumber( value ).toLocaleString( undefined, options ) :
                ''
        }
    }
```

```css
.input_date {
    margin:1px 0px 50px 0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #111;
    display: block;
    background: #ddd;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #111111;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
    <label for="cost_of_sale">Cost of Sale</label>
    <input class="input_date" type="currency" name="cost_of_sale" id="cost_of_sale" value="0.00">

    <label for="sales">Sales</label>
    <input class="input_date" type="currency" name="sales" id="sales" value="0.00">

     <label for="gm_pounds">GM Pounds</label>
     <input class="input_date" type="currency" name="gm_pounds" id="gm_pounds" value="0.00">
```

Comment: It is also a a very inefficient, wong way of binding events to multiple elements. The proper way has been *event delegation* for about a decade now.

Answer (score 2):

Well in the end I had to compromise by implementing a HTML5/CSS solution, forgoing increment buttons in IE (they're a bit broke in FF anyway!), but gaining number validation that the JQuery spinner doesn't provide. Though I have had to go with a step of whole numbers.

```css
span.gbp {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

span.gbp::before {
    float: left;
    content: "\00a3"; /* £ */
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 3px;
}

span.gbp input {
     width: 280px !important;
}
```

```html
<label for="broker_fees">Broker Fees</label>
<span class="gbp">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter whole GBP (&pound;) or zero for none" min="0" max="10000" step="1" value="" name="Broker_Fees" id="broker_fees" required="required" />
</span>
```

The validation is a bit flaky across browsers, where IE/FF allow commas and decimal places (as long as it's .00), where as Chrome/Opera don't and want just numbers.

I guess it's a shame that the JQuery spinner won't work with a number type input, but the docs explicitly state not to do that :-( and I'm puzzled as to why a number spinner widget allows input of any ascii char?

Comment: JSFiddle of above - https://jsfiddle.net/yz9w9g3r 

Tweak of JSFiddle but with step any and better positioning of currency character - https://jsfiddle.net/yz9w9g3r/1/

Comment: Great, but it should be noted that this isn't a very international solution. (Then again, browsers haven't got i18n for `<input type="number">` worked out properly yet, either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303940/how-to-handle-floats-and-decimal-separators-with-html5-input-type-number)

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem for accepting monetary values for Euro, since `<input type="number" />` can't display Euro decimal and comma format.

We came up with a solution, to use `<input type="number" />` for user input. After user types in the value, we format it and display as a Euro format by just switching to `<input type="text" />`. This is a Javascript solution though, cuz you need a condition to decide between "user is typing" and "display to user" modes.

Here the link with Visuals to our solution:
[Input field type "Currency" problem solved](https://dev.to/techworld_with_nana/input-field-type-currency-problem-solved-3gf1)

Hope this helps in some way!

Answer (score 1):

More easy and beautiful if you has vue.js **[v-money-spinner](https://github.com/joserick/v-money-spinner)** :)

[image]