# How to control HTML validation on number required field?

Tags: html, google-chrome, validation

I am creating a basic form and for some reason I am getting very strange HTML validation on my number field.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
<form id="custom_price_calculator">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
      <label for="inputCalculatorQty" class="font-weight-bolder">Quantity</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorQty" value="1" min="1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
      <label for="inputCalculatorUnitPrice" class="font-weight-bolder">Unit Price</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorUnitPrice" min="0.01" value="0.81" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
      <label for="inputCalculatorQty" class="font-weight-bolder">Origination</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorQty" value="100" min="1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mt-md-4 mb-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sweets btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i> Calculate price</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

You actually get the same issue in code above but different values...

[image]

See screenshot below of the validation message I am seeing on my website.

[image]

I don't understand why the Chrome HTML validation message is returning this message when the input code is simply this:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorUnitPrice" min="0.01" value="0.81" required>
```

Surely I should be able to put any value I want in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the **step** attribute must be set to **any** within the number form input that allows decimal values.

```html
<form id="custom_price_calculator">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
      <label for="inputCalculatorQty" class="font-weight-bolder">Quantity</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorQty" value="1" min="1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
      <label for="inputCalculatorUnitPrice" class="font-weight-bolder">Unit Price</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorUnitPrice" min="0.01" value="0.81" step=any required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-4 mb-3">
      <label for="inputCalculatorQty" class="font-weight-bolder">Origination</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCalculatorQty" value="100" min="1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mt-md-4 mb-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sweets btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i> Calculate price</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Please reference this Stack Overflow question: [html5 input for money/currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163889/html5-input-for-money-currency).