# Input Only Decimal Values for the input field's

Tags: angular7

I have a doubt, Please let me know how to proceed. Below the image, you can see there have two fields called **selling price** and **buying price**, I want to input there only decimal value for those mentioned fields please advise me to how to do that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i88R.jpg)

Thank You

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163889/html5-input-for-money-currency

Answer (score 0):

The solution isn't angular related.

Here's an older thread that shows the multiple ways you could accomplish this:
[Is there a float input type in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5)

Comment: Thank u for the answer