# PrimeReact InputNumber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, primereact

What I have to use, if I want that InputNumber to be clear? not with default value?
I use min and max for InputNumber and when I want to use InputNumber, this one set the default value to 0.

[image: 1]

Price is the InputNumber.

Comment: Use an empty value if you don't want it to be 0? `value=""` or in JS `.value = ""`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html5 input for money/currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163889/html5-input-for-money-currency)