# Firefox not reading trailing zeros, but chrome is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have a case where a user can enter `5.000` or `5.0` and my existing code will output `5.000` regardless, except if you are using Firefox it displays `5`. Here is what my code looks like

```
Util.fixPrecisionCallback = function (precision, keepLeadingZeros) {
    return function (e) {
        var value = $(e.target).val(),
            formatted = Util.formatPrecision(value, precision, keepLeadingZeros);

        if (value !== formatted) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(e.target).val(formatted)
        }
    }
};

Util.formatPrecision = function (value, precision, keepLeadingZeros) {

    var fval = parseFloat("" + value);
    fval = isNaN(fval) ? 0 : fval;
    fval = fval.toFixed(precision);

    if (!keepLeadingZeros)
        return fval;

    var leadingZeros = (value.match(Util.LEADING_ZEROS) || []).join("");
    var fvalLeadingZeros = (fval.match(Util.LEADING_ZEROS) || []).join("")

    if (fvalLeadingZeros.length < leadingZeros.length)
    {
        return leadingZeros.substring(0, leadingZeros.length - fvalLeadingZeros.length) + fval; 
    }
    else
    {
        return fval;
    }
};
```

This is applied on the `change` event of my input which looks like this

`<input type="number" step="any" min="0.100" max="20.000" maxLength="6" id="boxScanLockTimeInput" style="width:160px;" />`

```
_fixPrecision3 = Util.fixPrecisionCallback(3);
$("#boxScanWidthInput", self.displayContainer).on("focusout", function () {
    //stuff
}).on("change", _fixPrecision3);
```

This same page works fine in Chrome, but for some reason does not work with firefox [no errors, but always displays `5` instead of `5.000`]. I have other pages where this boiler plate code works fine on both browsers, but for the life of me I can not find out what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox is "helping" you by simplifying the number you put in the input box. Remove the `type="number"` attribute, and it will stop doing that.

And anything else that applies to number inputs, unfortunately.

Some solutions to *that* problem may be found in [How can I make the HTML5 number field display trailing zeroes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790561/how-can-i-make-the-html5-number-field-display-trailing-zeroes).