# Angular DecimalPipe Transform Not Working in Firefox

Tags: angular, formatting, angular-pipe

I am programmatically applying a DecimalPipe transform to format a number to have two decimal places. This works in Chrome, IE, and Edge. It is not working in Firefox (60.0.2).

```
<input class="hour-input" min="0" max="24" type="number" step=".01" [(ngModel)]="hours">

export class HourComponent {
    hours: string;
    constructor(private numberPipe: DecimalPipe) { }

    formatHours() {
        this.hours = this.numberPipe.transform(this.hours, '1.2-2');
    }
}
```

I thought this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021277/angular-2-currency-format-is-not-working-in-firefox-v24) that mentions the [intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl) package might be related, but I am already importing this polyfill. It was also my understanding that Angular [pipes no longer depend on the intl package](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10809) as of Angular v5. I am using the standard [LOCALE_ID](https://v5.angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes) pattern.

Note that the DecimalPipe does work in Firefox if used directly in the UI:

```
{{hours | number: '1.2-2'}}
```

Comment: I wonder if the input within angular is changing it back. Can you console log immediately after the assign line and see if it's correct? Also how do you invoke formatHours?

Comment: I'm invoking formatHours on blur. I added log before and after the transform, entered the value 1, and the console output "1" and then "1.00" - but the displayed value is still just "1" with no decimal places.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is just Firefox clearing decimal places for the number input, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790561/how-can-i-make-the-html5-number-field-display-trailing-zeroes

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. Hence the console log which is doing the right part :)

Comment: Found this longstanding (and angry) post about it:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003896

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this isn't an issue with Angular, but rather with Firefox's handling of number inputs. A number input in Firefox clears the zeros after the decimal place by default. This seems to be a [longstanding issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003896) with no standard solution yet.

Looks like this [band-aid fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7791694/1558392) might work. This involves dynamically changing the input type to number while the user is typing, but then changing it back to text on blur. Kind of hacky.

Would love to see Firefox implement a standard override or improved default for this.