# Firefox forces 0 to input value when the desired value is anther form of 0. Ex: 00.00. Is there anything that could be done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Firefox forces all forms of zero to be 0.  We are being asked to make the front end consistent if possible.  So when 0 comes in as the value we want to show 00.00 as this is a financial site.  I tested this outside my current code with both jquery and regular javascript.

```
document.getElementById('txtQuantity').value = '00.00';
$('#txtQuantity').val('00.00');
```

Both of those simple calls to set 00.00 come out as 0.  I thought about input masking this but we don't want to force clients to type out decimal placeholders when all they want to input is an integer.

Comment: Is the input a `type="number"`? If so this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790561/how-can-i-make-the-html5-number-field-display-trailing-zeroes

Comment: *Firefox forces all forms of zero to be 0* — what does that mean? You're working with the **string** `'00.00'`, which is in no sense a "form of zero".

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is `type="number"` as [@Rory hinted at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362946/firefox-forces-0-to-input-value-when-the-desired-value-is-anther-form-of-0-ex#comment97449893_55362946). Given `<input type="number" value="00.00">`, Firefox will show an element that contains the value, `0`.

It's not exactly semantic, but in my experience `tel` is more consistent across browsers. Note that this will also get rid of the spinner buttons (which in my use cases is preferred, but might not be in yours):

```html
<p>number: <input type="number" value="00.00"></p>
<p>tel: <input type="tel" value="00.00" pattern="\d+\.\d+"></p>
```

Firefox:
 [image: Firefox]

Chrome:
 [image: Chrome]

Edge (FWIW):
 [image: Edge]

Comment: tel is allowing me type alpha.  I checked w3 school and it looks like it's not supported on anything besides safari.  Looked promising when I read your answer.

Comment: @UNOBerry Correct. `tel` will allow you to type non-numeric characters, but (at least for me running FF 66.0) `number` does as well. You'll have to add your own validation / `onkeydown` handler to restrict inputs if that's required. You could use `pattern="\d+\.\d+` or similar (see updated answer) but that still allows you to type an invalid input.